# Set ID's dynamically to Web Controls

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs

I'm using AngularJS and I need to have a asp:Button Web Control in ng-repeat table cell. Since the button gets repeated with angular the ID will be always myButton. How can I generate the buttons IDs as myButton1, myButton2, myButton3 etc

```
   <tr data-ng-repeat="cell in Rows">
    <td><asp:Button ID="myButton" runat="server" 
        Text="Button" ClientIDMode="Static"/></td>  

     <td>cell</td>
   </tr>
```

Comment: You cannot use `ng-repeat` (or any client script for that matter) to create server-side controls

Comment: ok thanks, that clears it.

Comment: Why not use a `<asp:repeater` control? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/zzx23804(v=vs.80).aspx